# Consistent estimator and distribution function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, cumulative-distribution-function, consistency

<s>a general question:
If the distribution function $F_n$ of some estimator $T_n$ suffices
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(x) = 1 \text{ or } 0 \forall x}.</s>

Does that imply that $T_n$ is consistent?

I am not sure if this question in general even makes sense. But in this paper
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d64/5e60691838bf4699e79458d96930ba7bf24e.pdf
In the proof of theorem 1 the author uses this argument if I understand it correctly.

Updated question:

Let $n=b^k$ with $b \geq 3$ and odd. And let $x_1, \dots x_n$ be independent observations. The sample median of $b$ observations is denoted by $T_b$.
The remedian $T_{b^k} = T_b(T_{b^{k-1}}, \dots, T_{b^{k-1}})$.
The author claims:
If $F$ has a continuous density $f$ that is strictly positive at $\text{Med(F)}$. Then the remedian is consistent for $\text{Med(F)}$.

The proof of the author:
Let $b=2m+1$. The distribution function of the sample median is:
$G_b(x) = R_b(F(x))$ where $R_b(u) = \sum_{m+1}^b \binom{b}{j}u^j(1-u)^{b-j}$
Therefore the distribution function the the remedian is:
$G_{b^k} = R_b(R_b(\dots R_b(F(x)))) = R_b^{(k)}(F(x))$
He shows that $R_b$ is strictly convex for $u \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and strictly concave for $u \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

So far I understand it.

But then he shows that:

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} G_{b^k}(x) = 1$ for $x$ such that $F(x) > \frac{1}{2}$ and

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} G_{b^k}(x) = 0$ for $x$ such that $F(x) < \frac{1}{2}$

and then concludes that this proofs the consistency of $T_{b^k}$

Which I don't understand. And where is the strictly positive $f$ at $\text{Med(F)}$ needed?

Comment: Presumably by "suffices" you mean "satisfies."  Have you tried applying a definition of consistency?  What definition are you using?  It may be of interest to note there are consistent estimators that do *not* have this limiting property.  For instance, the sample mean of any continuous finite-variance distribution with mean $\mu$ does not have this property (because the limiting value of $F_n(\mu)$ is $1/2$).

Comment: @whuber sorry my initial question was wrong, I updated it so it makes more sense I hope

Comment: The expression $(5.2)$ for the distribution function of the median is correct only for continuous distributions and is asymptotically correct (in probability) only for distributions continuous in a neighborhood of their median.

Comment: I think I got it, I just have to use the definition of consistency:
$P(|T_{b^k}-\text{med(F)}| \geq \epsilon) = 1-G_{b^k}(\epsilon + \text{med(F)}) = 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and if $T_{b^k} \geq \text{med(F)}$ because of the first limit stated in the question. The other case works similar because of the second limit. I still dont quite understand why $f$ needs to be striclty positive at $\text{med(F)}$

Comment: Your formula reflects the right understanding, but it needs modification to $$P(|T_{b^k}-\operatorname{med}(F)|\gt\epsilon)\le 1-G_{b^k}(\epsilon+\operatorname{med}(F))+G_{b^k}(-\epsilon+\operatorname{med}(F)){\to}_{k\to\infty}(1-1)+0=0.$$ To see why continuity at the median is needed, consider the simplest possible $F$ that is not continuous at the median, such as a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution with $p\ne1/2.$ The sample median can only equal $0$ or $1,$ whence it must have a discrete distribution and therefore it cannot be given by $R_b.$